# How to trigger AF-assist light on Canon Speedlites without firing the flash?

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash

Most of Canon Speedlites flashes have quite nice built-in AF-assist LED lights, which would are useful in low-light situations, even when one doesn't want to use flash in photos.

Is there any way to set the flash (or camera) to fire only AF-assist, and not the flash itself? Only way I know is to prefocus and then turn off the flash, which is not very practical.

Comment: Same questionf or Nikon: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/897/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disable the flash in the camera settings. It still uses the AF-assist beam, but it will not fire the flash.

The setting is in different places depending on the camera, for example:

EOS 5D:
Menu > Custom Functions > 07

EOS 5D mk II:
Menu > Tools 3 > External Speedlite control > Flash function settings > Flash firing

EOS 550D / Rebel T2i / Kiss X4:
Menu > Camera 1 > Flash control > Flash firing
(it also works for built-in flash)

Comment: Thanks! Does the Mk II variant also work with non-recent models like 550EX or 580EX? I thought that camera-flash control was limited to 580EX II and 430EX II.

Comment: @che: Yes, I have a 550EX, and it works. Some of the settings only work with newer flashes, but disabling the flash works with older ones also.

Comment: You can't disable the flash and still have the AF assist lamp on the older 1 series Canons (1DmkI&II, 1Ds mkI&II) which is very annoying...

Comment: @Matt Grum: That's an odd limitation... Even my old D60 can do that. :P

Answer (score 2):

Generally this can be enabled through a custom function on your camera -- depending on your camera, the setting will be in a different place.

In low light situations, the flash may still strobe to assist in metering and determine how much flash power is required.

Comment: In camera's custom functions I've only found setting to enable/disable AF-assist beam, not having *only* the AF-assist :/

Answer (score 1):

EOS 5D (mk1) and 580EX II
AF-assist & no flash:

1. EOS 5D: {CF7: 1 (=flash off)} & {CF5: 0 (=send)}
2. 580EXII: {CF8: 0 (Af-assist light on}

Answer (score 0):

[Use an ST-E2](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/st-e2.shtml). It has a focus assist lamp but no flash head. :)